# Can an Elasticsearch decay function boost be inverted without using a script score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run text queries with results sorted by a combination of age and text search relevance, with older documents as well as ones with good textual matches being boosted towards the top.

Ideally the document score might be something like `(raw text match score) * (1 - gauss(origin=now, scale=30d))`

Is there any way of making the decay function prefer values that are far from the origin rather than near the origin? I don't want to use scripted sort because it is slower.